# Backbone.js: How to make the View handle the model's error?

Tags: javascript, validation, error-handling, backbone.js

Basically, I want my model to have its own validation logic while having the error being passed onto the View. Here's the code, and the link: http://jsfiddle.net/jancarlo000/aRFGm/3/

The result is 'undefined' instead of 'age cannot be 0'

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'FirstName':'JC'
    },   
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('new person');
    },
    validate: function(attr){
        if (attr.Age == 0){
            return 'age cannot be 0';
        }
    }
});

AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.model.bind('error', function(model, error){ 
                                    alert(model); alert(error); 
                                 }());
    }
});

var j = new Person();
var app = new AppView({model:j});
app.model.set({Age:0}); <=== purposely try to invoke validation error here..

//note: console's target must be result(fiddle.jshell.net) 
//in Chrome for it to work...
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem was that I added an unnecessary **invocation operator ()** at my function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.bind('error', function(model, error){ alert(model); alert(error); }());
  }
});
```

You don't need the function that you bind to be invoked immediately, remove the parens:

```
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.bind('error', function(model, error){ alert(model); alert(error); });
  }
});
```

And run your code: http://jsfiddle.net/aRFGm/4/

Comment: I just figured it just now when I double-checked it. Thanks for the help :) (will mark yours as answer when stackoverflow lets me)